# Is sails waterline find queries casesensitive?

Tags: postgresql, sails.js, waterline

I need to do a case insensitive `find()` in sails waterline.there is no configuration changed in sails model or postgresql(Data Base) connection ,but even then in get the result as `'undefined'` if i give 'Gary' where in db its stored as 'gray'.

Please help me to have a case insensitive search in sails waterline using postgresql db.

Comment: sry guys, i was using type as email in model ,so it was case Sensitive.Sails waterline is case insensitive unless explicitly change the configuration in connection.